# Why BrowserModule and HttpClientModule does not implement NgModule interface?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Just found that BrowserModule and HttpClientModule are not implementing NgModule interface. Could somebody explain why?

Update: the actual problem that I'm trying to solve is to extract *import* section to separate array that I can create based on specific rules. So the idea is **to specify the type of this array**. I don't want to put `any` here:

```
const importedModules: any[] = [
   BrowserModule,
   HttpClientModule,
   FormsModule,
   SharedModule,
   ...
];

if (!environment.production) {
  importedModules.push(StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument());
}

@NgModule({
   //...
   imports: importedModules,
   //...
})
```

Comment: Sounds more a question for the developers than Stack

Comment: what do you mean by `NgModule` interface?

Comment: The NgModule interface is used to define the NgModule decorator (which both BrowserModule & HttpClientModule use). The actual BrowserModule class does not implement the NgModule interface directly (`export class BrowserModule implements NgModule`). This is because the providers, declarations, imports, exports, etc.. are defined within the decorator, not within the class itself.